# is it possible to stop auto increment in mysql for particular record and store duplicate number

Tags: mysql

i want to insert a duplicated value into table which have auto_increamented colum.

can i insert like this

```
auto_incremet
 +---------------+---------
| invoiceNumber | totalAmt | 
+---------------+----------+
|             1 |      200 |  
|             0        158
|             2 |     1200 | 
|             0        122 |
|             3         65  |
|             4 |      240 |          
|             5 |      330 |          
|             6 |       80 |          
+---------------+---------
```

i do not want to increment the value for particular record .

is it possible to do so?

it is possible with additional table so that i can send particular records to other table and stop it increment in first table.

but cant it be done with same table ?

Comment: I highly doubt that this is possible and I think is one of the worst sins you can commit in a database.

Comment: Why would you want to??

Comment: I think you want to do something else and you're thinking about it in the wrong way.

Comment: Even if possible this should be avoided. Restructure your database.

Comment: You can give a number to an increment table, but you pay with it with a part of your soul. Different database engines react differently to it, some sets the autoincrementer to the new value, some continues from the next empty one... you should check the relevant manual.

Comment: i dont want to give invoice number for particular record but in want to preserve that record for calculations @ shawkins1

Comment: Hmm, it is not stated if this auto_increment table is some kind of key though...

Comment: it can be possible if i add another table for which i dont want the invoice number., but can't it be done in the same table.

Comment: Is the invoice number an auto_increment column , if so is it a primary key or unique key or a non-unique key, what does an invoice id of 0 indicate?

Comment: its a primary key @P.Salmon 0 is the record for which i want skip auto increment and insert some standard value instead sequence number

Comment: A primary key cannot be duplicated. Question answered.

Comment: can i insert any other unique number every time i needed instead sequence number @ deceze♦

Comment: Duplicating primary keys is stupid, but my bloodthirsty god likes it. I would select the current AI id somehow (like, select * from tbl order by auto desc limit 1), store it somewhere, edit the table, then ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT=storedvalue;. Apparently the DB does not like duplicated primary keys.

Comment: That's a yes though, giving not used primary keys works, but changes the AI to that one.

Comment: ufff lengthy ,is it a good practice to use another table for those records?

Comment: That entirely depends on what you want to do. Personally I have a primary key for every individual table, and if needed, and index key that can be used to connect with other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it can't be 0. It could be 1, though.

```
MariaDB [wow]> create table test ( id int(11) not null auto_increment, name varchar(15), key id (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [wow]> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'mark');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [wow]> insert into test (id, name) values (0, 'allan');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [wow]> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'patrick');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [wow]> insert into test (name) values ('chris');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [wow]> insert into test (name) values ('oliver');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [wow]> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'damien');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Observe:

```
MariaDB [wow]> select * from test;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | mark    |
|  2 | allan   |
|  1 | patrick |
|  3 | chris   |
|  4 | oliver  |
|  1 | damien  |
+----+---------+
```

Obviously this is not a very good idea. Create a second column and call it invoice_id. Increment it using a sequence table.

But yes, to answer the question, although auto_increment must be on a key, it does not need to be on a UNIQUE key such as the primary key.

Comment: AI must not be a key (but generally a good idea). You can also have multiple AI columns with different increments. The primary key must be unique, but not necessarily an AI.

Comment: ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Unlike what @maaarghk asserts, you can set it to zero if you like by doing, e.g., this after the insert: "update test set id=0 where id=2"

Comment: That's a great idea, infact the same could be achieved as per the question's request using a trigger. Exercise for the reader.

Comment: There's only one auto column in this definition.

Comment: Mea culpa. There can't be multiple AI columns in a table, also must be the primary key.

Comment: Correct, there can't be multiple AI cols. However, an AI col doesn't have to be the PK, or even UNIQUE, it just has to have an index on it as the example above shows.